# Android AlertDialog The specified child already has a parent Exception

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a little issue with `AlertDialog` on my application. I'm showing an `AlertDialog` so user can change the text of the button he just pressed. When I do that the first time there is no problem, but if I press the button again my application crashes with the Exception in the title. Here is the code which I'm using :

```
public void createDialog(){
     new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this)
    .setTitle("Stampii Server Name")
    .setView(input)
    .setPositiveButton("Set Name", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String serverName = input.getText().toString();
            server.setText(serverName);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).show();
}


server.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        createDialog();
    }
});
```

Any ideas how can I fix that problem? I've looked at the questions similar to this, but can't find a working solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check at which line it is crashing in CreateDialog method..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.setView(input)
```

The variable "input" is not created in the method and is being added to a new dialog every time. This means, every time you call your create method, you are trying to add a new parent to the same object. You will need a new "input" every time you create the dialog, or you could use the same dialog over and over again.

Comment: I forget about the `EditText`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once. I was using showDialog(int id,Bundle args) and implemented

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id,Bundle args)
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case ...:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositive...
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

My mistake was that i had to use removeDialog(int id) before creating a new dialog since Android is somehow caching the dialog and doesn't call onCreateDialog() every time you call showDialog().
So my solution was calling

```
removeDialog(id);
showDialog(id,args);
```

and modifying the onCreateDialog() by removing all possible dialogs before the switch-statement to avoid conflicts with any other cached dialog.